# Virtual methods to populate on mongoose 'init'

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm looking to find a way to populate virtuals ( or something similar ) to a mongoose model.

I have a model which I would like to have non persisted properties.

I'm attempting to have the ability to have helping pointers such as 'isFavourited : true' on the model init instead of looping through results and decorating these values.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtuals will certainly do this for you out of the box:

```
someSchema.virtual('isFavourited').get(function() {  
    return true
})
```

It would give you a transient isFavorited property that can't be set.

What you might want to get arbitrary transient properties on a model is a plugin that looks something like this:

```
function IHaveContext(schema, init={}) {
   schema.virtual('context')
        .get(function () {
            return this._context;
        })
        .set(function (item) {
            if (!this._context)
                this._context = init;
            this._context = Object.assign({}, this._context, item);
        });

}
```

Then you apply this to any model, optionally setting up defaults:

```
let Game = new Schema({ ... })
Game.plugin(IHaveContext, {'isFavourited': false})
```

Now you have an api to decorate your model with arbitrary properties:

```
let item - new Game()
item.set('context', {'isFavourited': true});
item.get('context')('isFavourited');
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

Schema.set("toObject", { virtuals: true });
Schema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });

will render the virtuals on the object/s when returned from finds

Comment: Ahh that was your question.  My misunderstanding.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Your answer helped me get to the correct solution with a async schema extender plugin with the same virtual setup that you posted above. Thank you!